# Python Keycloak Error - Public client not allowed to retrieve service account

Tags: python, client, keycloak, admin

I'm trying to get keycloak_admin instance in my code as described in documentation
https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/

```
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                               username='example-admin',
                               password='secret',
                               realm_name="master",
                               user_realm_name="only_if_other_realm_than_master",
                               client_secret_key="client-secret",
                               verify=True)
```

But I'm getting this error:
**KeycloakAuthenticationError: 401:
b'{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Public client not allowed
to retrieve service account"}'**

I'm pretty sure my client is set to **CONFIDENTIAL**, not PUBLIC, so I don't know why this error appeared. Any suggestions what could go wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by following the steps from this tutorial:
https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-rest-api-create-a-new-user/

It is a little confusing that error message was referring **to "admin-cli" client, NOT my custom client** which I'm normally using.

Answer (score 1):

If your setup has multiple realm then make sure you are using the right token endpoint when requesting access token. The token endpoint will change based on which realm you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> user_realm_name

Admin can only connect to master realm, an afterwards they can manage other realms. This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass client_id=settings.KEY_CLOAK_CLIENT_ID,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32683558)